# Macbook to iPhone tether, hotspot or wifi

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, wifi, tethering

If I am connected to wifi on my iPhone, and I turn on my personal hotspot, and then tether to my MacBook will my MacBook use the wifi that my iPhone is connected to or will it use my data via personal hotspot? MacBook is not connected to wifi, only the usb tether to the iPhone, which is connected to wifi.

Answer (score 2):

When using you iPhone as a hotspot, it will use your data plan. In the screenshots you see my iPhone connected to WiFi, and when a device is connected to it's hotspot, my iPhone will be disconnected from the WiFi.

iPhone connected to WiFi:
[image: iPhone connected to WiFi]

iPhone not connected to WiFi, but network still available
[image: iPhone not connected to WiFi, but network still available]

Comment: Don't see why this answer was down voted. Seems like a good explanation to me.

Comment: Because "usb tether to the iPhone", not wifi to the iphone. Also, Dutch UI.